# jQuery elements fail to select parent()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

It seems elements selected using `:contains(sub)` with `sub` containing `<` or `>` cannot get to their parents.

The following example should illustrate the problem I'm having in both Safari and Camino (Gecko on Mac):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><strong>bar</strong></p>
  <p><strong>&lt;foo&gt;</strong></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
alert($('body strong:contains("bar")').length);
alert($('body strong:contains("bar")').parent().length);
alert($('body strong:contains("<foo>")').length);
alert($('body strong:contains("<foo>")').parent().length); // this fails
alert($('body strong').length);
alert($('body strong').parent().length); // two p elements
alert($('body strong').parent().parent().length); // one body
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Output is:

```
1
1
1
0
2
2
1
```

Any ideas why the fourth one is `0` instead of `1`, or how I can circumvent this?

[This page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) mentions escaping names in selectors, but that didn't work either (also, I'm not sure if it's applicable).

Comment: need expert opinion on "contains"

Comment: The node is actually being interpreted as a document fragment, very odd indeed.

Comment: `alert($('body strong:contains("<foo>")').is('strong')); // false`

Comment: @Matt - It's "foo" that's the weird part: `alert($('body strong:contains("<foo>")')[0].nodeName);` it thinks it's a document fragment.

Comment: alert($('body strong:contains("<foo>")')[0].tagName); // FOO

Comment: Bottom line, this looks like a bug in the contains() where it should treat everything as text in the () except the quotes but does not and is using the ">" improperly in this case.  Very interesting this is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what's causing `contains()` to fail, but you can use `.filter()` as an alternative:

```
alert($('body strong').filter(function() {
    return /<foo>/.test( $(this).text() );
}).parent().length);
```

That returns 1 as expected. It's ugly, but works.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: This isn't a solution/workaround use [Tatu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812280/jquery-elements-fail-to-select-parent/3812410#3812410) for that, this is just a description of the problem and what's going on to cause the weird behavior for those who are curious.*

The root of the problem is here, [the regex that jQuery uses to identify an HTML Fragment](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L20):

```
/^[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|^#([\w-]+)$/
```

Which *does* match your selector:

```
body strong:contains("<foo>")
```

[You can try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4QfT2/):

```
alert(/^[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|^#([\w-]+)$/.test('body strong:contains("<foo>")​​​'));​
```

So it thinks it's an HTML fragment..so overall these are currently equivalent:

```
$('body strong:contains("<foo>")');
$('<foo>');
```

Seeing the second is a clearer illustration that it's a document fragment...which has no parent.  It takes the 2nd position in the match array, which you can see is just `<foo>`, [again try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4QfT2/1/):

```
alert(/^[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|^#([\w-]+)$/.exec('body strong:contains("<foo>")')[1]);​
```

This results in you ultimately ending up at [this code path in jQuery's `$()`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L131), building a fragment.

So in short **yes**, I'd consider this a jQuery bug.

Answer (score 1):

The `<foo>` is being evaluated as a tag, thus the parent of it contains nothing except an empty tag, thus the 0.

EDIT:  To fully understand look at this: `$('body strong:contains("foo")').text().length` which yeilds 5.  The 1 from `$('body    strong:contains("<foo>")').length` says there is one text node within the strong so length of that is 1 and the length of the text is 5.

The thing that gets interesting is the trailing `&gt;` which cannot be selected correctly as the `>` nor the `&gt;` seem to work due to the `>` which is used as a css selector. So, `<foo` works but not `<foo>`

Here is a fiddle page to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/2XEUg/1/

Comment: The `:contains()` is a filter on the `:strong()` so this really doesn't cover it, they both have parents in the document...

Comment: probably some weird part of the "text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as bare words or surrounded by quotation marks." evaluation for the `>`.

Comment: @Nick Craver - note that :contains() looks in any decendant (I know you knew this)

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the match isn't *on* the descendant, it's a filter on the parent, e.g. `something:contains('somethingElse')` the selector should match *nothing* but a `<strong>` element, no matter how deep the contained text is.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly an issue with jQuery's selector parsing.  If `<` and `>` are present in the selector, jQuery identifies the argument as a document fragment instead of a selector.  The result is an element with a *tagName* of "FOO", and the same selectors would have the same issue:

```
$('body <foo>')
$('body strong:not(<foo>')
```

The only difference in your case is that you've used a valid selector and jQuery is identifying it incorrectly.

I made several attempts at a selector-based workaround, but [Tatu Ulmanen's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812280/jquery-elements-fail-to-select-parent/3812410#3812410) was the only one that worked.

EDIT: it seems you can also use *.find()*:

```
$(document.body).find('strong:contains("<foo>")')
```

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. Do you think it's useful to file a bug with jQuery?

Comment: @Daniel: yes, they might be able to fix this or provide a better workaround in the next version.